# understanding init and method calling in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, number_of_wheels, type_of_tank, seating_capacity, maximum_velocity):
        self.number_of_wheels = number_of_wheels
        self.type_of_tank = type_of_tank
        self.seating_capacity = seating_capacity
        self.maximum_velocity = maximum_velocity

    @property
    def number_of_wheels(self):
        return self.number_of_wheels

    @number_of_wheels.setter
    def number_of_wheels(number):
        self.number_of_wheels = number

    def make_noise(self):
        print('VRUUUUUUUM')

tesla_model_s = Vehicle(4, 'electric', 5, 250)
print('number of wheels',tesla_model_s.number_of_wheels) # 4
tesla_model_s.number_of_wheels = 2 # setting number of wheels to 2
print('updated number of wheels',tesla_model_s.number_of_wheels) # 2
tesla_model_s.make_noise() # VRUUUUUUUM
```

when I run this code I got the below error.I think it might be because of getter and setter . Can anyone please help me sort this .

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "classes.py", line 23, in <module>
        tesla_model_s.make_noise() # VRUUUUUUUM
    AttributeError: Vehicle instance has no attribute 'make_noise'
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Since your exception occurs at line 23, which your sample code doesn't have, it's apparent that you have some extra lines in your actual code. Please post your actual code so we can help.

Comment: Is the indentation on the `def make_noise(self):` line correct? As written, i cant see any reason this wouldnt work.

Comment: i have only included extra getter and setter in the code nothing else..then it shows the above error.

Comment: Can't reproduce.